# MongoDB - How to write a nested group aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection in this format:

```
{
  "place":"land",
  "animal":"Tiger",
  "name":"xxx"
},
{
  "place":"land",
  "animal":"Lion",
  "name":"yyy"
}
```

I want to result to be something like this:

```
{
  "place":"land".
  "animals":{"Lion":"yyy", "Tiger":"xxx"}
}
```

I wrote the below query. I think there needs to be another group stage but not able to write it.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  '$group': {
  '_id':{'place':'$place', 'animal':'$animal'},
  'animalNames': {'$addToSet':'$name'}
  }
})
```

What changes need to be made to get the required result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by `animals`. Push objects with `{ k: "animal", v: "name" }` type into `animals` array.
2. `$project` - Decorate output document. Convert `animals` array to key-value pair via `$arrayToObject`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$place",
      "animals": {
        "$push": {
          k: "$animal",
          v: "$name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      place: "$_id",
      animals: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$animals"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MAnVmgiWifI)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on version >=4.4, a reasonable alternative is to use the `$function` operator:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        'income_statement.annual': {
            $function: {
                body: function(arr) {                      
                    return arr.sort().reverse();
                },
                args: [ "$income_statement.annual" ],
                lang: "js"
            }}
    }}
]);
```

Comment: Animals need lots of help determining their annual income.  8-)